# get different name from jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this function to get autocomplete on input value

```
<input type="text" id="product_name">

$( '#product_name' ).autocomplete({
  source:'autocomplete.php',
  minLength:2,
  select: function(event,ui){
    $('#product_name').val( ui.item.name );
  }
});
```

but the line

```
$('#product_name').val( ui.item.name );
```

doesn't work...

From php I store in json, "value" that is product name with different attribute, and in "name", ONLY the product name

Then, when I search with 2 digits, the results are like

```
product1 - qt:0 - price:20
product2 - qt:4 - price:7
product3 - qt:3 - price:11
```

and when I select I want to update my input only with name that is stored in `ui.item.name`

This is my autocomplete.php

```
$sql = "SELECT name, CONCAT (quantity,' - ',name,' - ',price) AS value
    FROM `product` ";

$res= $db->query($sql);
while ($r = $res->fetch()) {
  $a_json_row["name"] = r['name'];
  $a_json_row["value"] = $r['value'];
  array_push($a_json, $a_json_row );
}

echo json_encode($a_json);
flush();
```

Json returned from autocomplete.php is:

```
 [{
  "name": "MOCCOLO 60X165",
  "value": "[12] - MOCCOLO 60X165 : 4.00"
  }, {
   "name": "MOCCOLO 80X150",
   "value": "[19] - MOCCOLO 80X150 : 6.50"
  }, {
   "name": "MOCCOLO 80X200",
   "value": "[69] - MOCCOLO 80X200 : 8.00"
 }]
```

This is when I search
[image]

This is when I select
[image]

But I want

[image]

Comment: can i see your code? or link

Comment: Provide an example of the server returned json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your php was at fault. Your ide/editor should have warned of such a simple mistake. You need to invest on better tools..

```
$sql = "SELECT name, CONCAT (quantity,' - ',name,' - ',price) AS value
FROM `product` ";

$a_json = [];
$res    = $db->query($sql);
while ($r = $res->fetch()) {
  $a_json[] = [
      "name"  => $r['name'],
      "value" => $r['value']
  ];
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($a_json);
flush();
```

Then, your JS should be like this:

```
$('#product_name').autocomplete({
  source: "autocomplete.php",
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#product_name').val(ui.item['name']);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Working [example](http://codepen.io/yivi/pen/MbMRNL?editors=1010#0).

Comment: Ok, is better in that way, but result is the same... My autocomplete work as yours, but when I select from list, my input "product_name" must update with "name" not "value"

Comment: Again, can you provide an example of the actual JSON returned? Your code was missing an $, so the json probably didn't have what you expected.

Comment: Can you get the produced json? You need only to call autocomplete.php...

Comment: Sorry my english is very poor and can be that I have not explained properly
my problem... I have uploaded some image... If you need I can create a new page with database to upload to a server but I need time....

Comment: The image is very nice, but not what I needed. I want the JSON that your autocomplete.php creates.

Comment: Sorry can't understand... You asking for this?

[{"name":"MOCCOLO 60X165","value":"[12] - MOCCOLO 60X165 : 4.00"},{"name":"MOCCOLO 80X150","value":"[19] - MOCCOLO 80X150 : 6.50"},{"name":"MOCCOLO 80X200","value":"[69] - MOCCOLO 80X200 : 8.00"}]